# Azure Graph - Retrieve user by ImmutableId - Filter issue

Tags: api, graph, azure-active-directory

I am trying to look up Azure user using the Immutable ID but it is not working.
Looking up the Azure user manually, I can see that the immutable id is populated, (actual attribute name is 'immutableId'), and matching what I am trying to query.

Actually I have not been able to retrieve any users using any filter, for example:
[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?&api-version={version}?$filter=startswith(displayName,'{startofuid}')](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/users?&api-version=%7Bversion%7D?$filter=startswith(displayName,%27%7Bstartofuid%7D%27))

Different test uris:

[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?&api-version={version}?$filter=immutableId](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/users?&api-version=%7Bversion%7D?$filter=immutableId) eq '{id}'

[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?&api-version={version}?$filter=immutableId+eq+'{id}'](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/users?&api-version=%7Bversion%7D?$filter=immutableId+eq+%27%7Bid%7D%27)

[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?&api-version={version}?$filter=startswith(immutableId,'{id}')](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/users?&api-version=%7Bversion%7D?$filter=startswith(immutableId,%27%7Bid%7D%27))

[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users?&api-version={version}?$filter=startswith(immutableId%2C+'{id}')](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/users?&api-version=%7Bversion%7D?$filter=startswith(immutableId%2C+%27%7Bid%7D%27))

Normal resource lookup works:

[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/users/{azureguid}?&api-version={version}](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/users/%7Bazureguid%7D?&api-version=%7Bversion%7D)

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Try to use: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=onPremisesImmutableId+eq+'{id}'`

Answer (score 1):

Starting on June 30, 2020, Microsoft will officially no longer add any new features to the Azure AD Graph API. It is recommended that you upgrade your application to use **Microsoft Graph API** instead of **Azure AD Graph API** to access Azure Active Directory resources.

You can use the **onPremisesImmutableId** property to retrieve the user.Then use the [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) tool to test, don’t forget to grant permissions to your api.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the great comment. A somewhat related question, I'd like to do the same with groups as well, but it doesn't seem like immutableid is retrieved by the api. I can see the attribute onpremisesamaccountname looking up the group but I cannot filter on it using either Azure Graph or Microsoft Graph

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working with this exact syntax:
[https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/{resourcetype}?`$filter=startswith(immutableId,'{id}')&api-version=1.6](https://graph.windows.net/%7Btenant%7D/%7Bresourcetype%7D?%60$filter=startswith(immutableId,%27%7Bid%7D%27)&api-version=1.6)

Answer (score -1):

Get-AzureADUser -Filter "immutableid eq 'ABCD'"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please could you edit your answer to include more information.